# NGINX get http version of request in location

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location, nginx-ingress

in nginx config, i want to return 401 if request's http version is either not present or is < 1.
something like the below:-

```
location / {
   if ($requestHttpVersion = '' OR $requestHttpVersion != 1.1){
    return 401;
    }
}
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works and i believe this is a better solution

```
http{
    map $server_protocol $httpVersion {
            default "invalid";
            HTTP/1.1 "valid";
            HTTP/1.0 "valid";
            HTTP/2.0 "valid";
    }

    location / {
        if ( $httpVersion = "invalid" )
        {
            return 401;
        }
        proxy_pass ....
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed this looks a better solution, didn't know about `$server_protocol` variable before. Some more optimized solution is `map $server_protocol $disallow_access { HTTP/1.0 ""; HTTP/1.1 ""; HTTP/2.0 ""; default 1; }` and `if ($disallow_access) { return 401; }`.

Answer (score 1):

You should check a [`$request`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request) built-in nginx variable which contain the full original request line which is usually something like `GET <URI> HTTP/<version>`:

```
if ($request !~ \sHTTP/1\.1$) {
    return 401;
}
```

Comment: I'm not talking about the version "Header". I m talking about the header that is sent as part of the request. was wondering if that is being set in any nginx variables

Comment: @CarlssonEvert All the HTTP request headers are accessible via [`$http_<header_name>`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_) variables, and your example used the `$http_version` variable, that's the reason I mentioned that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - i will edit the variable name to prevent confusion

Comment: there seems to be a better way - 

map $server_protocol $prot {
        default "null";
        HTTP/1.1 yes;
        HTTP/1.0 yes;
        HTTP/2.0 yes;
    }

 

Add in location block:
if ( $prot = "null" )
                {
                   return 504;
                }